# Cannot install "raster" package in R

Tags: r, package, raster

I am trying to use the raster package in R but since I bought a new computer and have the latest version of R on macOS it mentions certain packages are not available for this version of R.

I tried downloading R directly on R studio and that gave me errors.

Next I tried installing directly from GitHUB using the following command:

```
install.packages('raster', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

and this is the error message I receive:

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘terra’

Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘terra’ ‘raster’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source packages ‘terra’, ‘raster’

trying URL 'https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/terra_1.6-43.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1777090 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

trying URL 'https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/raster_3.6-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1310884 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang -arch arm64
configure: CXX: clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’
* removing ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library/terra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘terra’ is not available for package ‘raster’
* removing ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library/raster’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/zp/vysqcnr95g5d08jhlmzrvj9m0000gn/T/Rtmpn4J6eA/downloaded_packages’
```

When I load raster next this is what I see:

```
library(raster)
#Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’ in #loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
# there is no package called ‘terra’
```

When i try to install Terra this is the error message I see:

```
> install.packages('terra')
Installing package into ‘/Users/sofigreen/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/terra_1.6-41.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 99009623 bytes (94.4 MB)
===============
downloaded 28.7 MB

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 30079735 != reported length 99009623
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/terra_1.6-41.tgz': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.2/terra_1.6-41.tgz' failed
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘terra’ failed
```

And when trying to download terra from source:

```
> install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
Installing package into ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘terra’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘terra’

trying URL 'https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/src/contrib/terra_1.6-43.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1786823 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** using staged installation
configure: CC: clang -arch arm64
configure: CXX: clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++11
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’
* removing ‘/Users/username/Library/R/arm64/4.2/library/terra’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/zp/vysqcnr95g5d08jhlmzrvj9m0000gn/T/RtmpfniygU/downloaded_packages’
```

I really need the raster package. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have **Rtools** installed on your system ([click here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)). Then try the following steps:

1- When you open RStudio, right-click on the icon and choose `Run as Administrator.

2- Temporarily deactivate your firewall or antivirus.

3- Use the following commands:

```
install.packages('raster', dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://CRAN.R-project.org/')
library(raster)
```

See if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your question and show what happens when you run

```
install.packages('terra')
install.packages('raster')
```

I would not install from source code if you do not have to. But if you must, first install "terra". See https://github.com/rspatial/terra for instructions about installing from source code.